# How to edit the variables of a php file with another php file

Tags: php

Ok so I want to do something similar to how Simple Machine Forum edits some variable within the Admin panel on the forum. For instance
I have a **settings.php** file. I want **tool.php** to open and find all declared php variables in the **settings.php** like ***$background_color='Orange'*** and output in **tools.php** *Background Color: Orange* inside of a form tag that, once changed to **'Purple'** and submitted, replaces **'Orange'** with **'Purple'** and now if i open **'settings.php'** the variable inside the file is now ***"$background_color='Purple'"*** without having to go in an manually edit it. I can just submit the new data for the variable and replace the old.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901521/replace-string-in-text-file-using-php) may help you.

Comment: This is a notoriously precarious situation.  First off, from a security standpoint there are many types of permissions situations that will virtually guarantee this won't work.  It's also potentially a huge security hole because when you have a system that can write .php files, any mistake you make or that the user makes, is a major vector into exploitation and privileged code execution.  Overall it's a bad idea.  Most packages have a simple limited config.php file which just requires database credentials, and then keeps the majority of your name=value variables in the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the data persistent, you will need to store data in a database or separate file e.g. JSON file. Then you can use that data everywhere it is needed.

Here is an example using a JSON file.

setting_variables.json:

```
{
    "background": "red",
    "color": "white"
}
```

settings.php

```
$settings = json_decode(file_get_contents("settings_variables.json"), true);
$background = $settings['background'];
```

tools.php

```
include ("settings.php");

// If form is posted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    /* Updating variables in JSON file*/

    //Get settings_json file
    $setting_vars = json_decode(file_get_contents('settings_variables.json'), true);

    // Update variable
    $background = $setting_vars['background'] = $_POST['color'];

    // Store variable value to JSON file
    file_put_contents("settings_variables.json", json_encode($setting_vars));
}

?>

<form method="post" <?php echo "style='background-color:".$background . "'"; ?>>
    <select name="color">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="purple">purple</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks :D I wanted to avoid using the database option, I had already considered it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using database
fetch that value from database in settings.php
and update that from your  tools.php or wherever you want .

Answer (score 0):

To load the variables in tool.php, simply `include("settings.php")`.

In order to change settings, you will need to modify settings.php.

The easiest way to do this should be by regex-replacing the old value with the new one, e.g. `["\$background_color *= *'\d*'"]` and replace that with `["\$background_color = 'Purple'"]`.

Just overwrite the file with the new string.

I'm not sure I escaped everything correctly, but this way you should be able to replace the whole file.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

The drawback is, that if the settings file is very large, it may take some time to do that, although that will probably not be a problem for your use case.

alternatively, you could read the file line by line and replace that (either manually or by using regex-replacing again.