# PHP replace/update a line in large text file

Tags: php

Let's consider we got following format text file with a size around `1Gb`:

```
...
li1
li2
li3
...
```

My task is to update line `li2` to `line2`.

Following will not work:

```
$fd = fopen("file", 'c+');

// ..
// code that loops till we reach li2 line..
// ..
$offset = ftell($fd);
// ..

fseek($fd, $offset );
fwrite($fd, "line2" . PHP_EOL);
```

Since it produces:

```
...
li1
line2
3
...
```

I'm expecting to have as result:

```
...
li1
line2
li3
...
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901576/3044080

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion we need a temporary file here where we copy the non-changed result, add the change and continue with non-changed result. At the end the original file may be renamed and the temp file to take its name.

As I am familiar with file systems you cannot just delete/insert part of the file. Or it is just too complicated and it is not worthy.

Second - you can copy the file in the memory and make your modifications there but here you are resource dependent and your code may not pass on some servers (e.g. dedicated hosting).

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you know what you must change in text just use this:

```
$file_data=file_get_contents(some_name.txt);
$text = str_replace("line2", "li2", $file_data);
file_put_contents('some_name_changed.txt',  $text);
```

Or read line by line and load in $text then replace what you want.