# Find and Replace Curl Output PHP

Tags: php, regex, curl, explode

I have two websites.   I would like to curl to a page on website #1 to retrieve html code which has links to my favorite twitch streams, embed in to my page using their api.   Using this curl output, I would like to find and replace iterations of my website #1 and replace it with mywebsite #2.

Ie)   Curl to mywebsite1.com/myfavoritestreams  > retrieves  "mywebsite1.com/stream1"

I want to find, replace and display "mywebsite2.com/stream1" instead.

[using this stackoverflow questions as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901521/replace-string-in-text-file-using-php) I tried variations of this with no success.  Just error messages that it expects a valid string and path.

All help is appreciated.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite1.com/myfavoritestreams");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Host: www.wiz1.net";
$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$headers[] = "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";
$headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Referer: http://www.mywebsite1.com";
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9";
$headers[] = "Cookie: __cfduid=d00d780044d6524dab736999f38359bba1534699518; _ga=GA1.2.1974576514.1534699525; _gid=GA1.2.795232845.1540262479";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$filename = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
$string_to_replace="mywebsite1";
$replace_with="mywebsite2";
replace_string_in_file($filename, $string_to_replace, $replace_with);

function replace_string_in_file($filename, $string_to_replace, $replace_with){
    $content=file_get_contents($filename);
    $content_chunks=explode($string_to_replace, $content);
    $content=implode($replace_with, $content_chunks);
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);
}
```

Comment: is the curl not working or is the output just not what you expected?

Comment: You appear to be calling your curl response as a file name?
$newOutput = str_ireplace("mywebsite1", "mywebsite2", $filename)

Comment: Why would another website return a filename on your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I don't think you can use the curl response body as the file name.
You can do something like this.

```
$body = curl_exec($ch);
$output = str_replace($string_to_replace,$replace_with,$body);
$filename = "/tmp/temp.txt" // here you need to put a valid path to a file
$file = fopen($filename,'w+');
fwrite($file,$body);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Excellent.   I understand this now!!