# How to replace text inside a PHP Document?

Tags: php

I am making a wordpress plugin, you can edit a page's title with it.
The title will be an H1 Tag with the ID of featuredTitle.

```
<h1 id="featuredTitle">This text will be replaced!</h1>
```

Now I need an input that opens the file "myPage.php" and replaces the text.
I am new to PHP so help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace string in text file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901521/replace-string-in-text-file-using-php)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping cant get it to work.