# php replace an string on exist file .env

Tags: php

my question is similiar like this : [Replace string in text file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901521/replace-string-in-text-file-using-php/24240869)

but i want replace by spesification variable
for example, i have already file exist `.env`

```
variable_1=data_2021
variable_99=data_2050
variable_991=data_2061
```

so how i can replace by spesificiation name variable for the value ?
i want replace `data_2050` with `data_2051` without change on other text where the variable is `variable_99`

```
        $myfile = fopen("../../.env.securepay", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, 'variable_99='.$value);
        fclose($myfile);

        // $myfile = fopen("../../.env", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        // fseek($myfile, 0);
        // fwrite($myfile, 'variable_99 ='.$value);
        // fclose($myfile);

        // $oldMessage = 'variable_99';
        // $deletedFormat = '';

        // //read the entire string
        // $str=file_get_contents('../../.env.securepay');

        // //replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
        // $str=str_replace($oldMessage, $deletedFormat, $str);

        // //write the entire string
        // file_put_contents('../../.env', $str);
```

above code just remove all the content file `.env` and re added `variable_99=value`

Comment: use `file()`, it will conver file to array, then iterate over it and replace and then do `fwrite()` or `file_put_contents()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_put_contents` and `parse_ini_file` like this follow below

```
function modifyEnv($path,$values = []) {
    $env = [];
    foreach(parse_ini_file($path) as $k => $value) {
        if(in_array($k,array_keys($values))) {
            $env[$k] = "$k={$values[$k]}";
        }
    }
    return file_put_contents($path,implode(PHP_EOL,$env));
}
```

Then you can call like this, you can replace multiple `.env` variables by using `array key, value`. `key` is the `old value` and the `value` is the `new value`

```
modifyEnv('../../.env.securepay',[
    'variable_99' => 'data_2051',
    'variable_1' => 'data_2051'
]);
```

Comment: ``` 'variable_99' => 'variable_99=data_2051'  ```
but my conditions i dont know my value, so when i try the code the output is ```variable_1=data_2021
variable_99=data_2051=data_2050```

Comment: the code still replace all string , my question is `without change on other text ` so i only want to change some variable only, for example is variable_99. other variable is constanta.